# internet sharing with d-link wireless router

Tags: router

I need to share my Internet connection to other computers. I don't know how to set it up.

I have 3 computers and a router. All 3 PCs have wireless adapters and ethernet cards. One of them is connected to the Internet through a USB 3G Modem. The modem is very small, and it does not have an ethernet port that could be connected to the router. I'm saying that because most of the tutorials/guides on the Web suggest that I should connect my modem to the 1st port of the router.

Answer (score 1):

Those guides are not for USB 3G modems.

You have only two possibilities here:

1. Buy one of the 3G routers. These are routers that have a USB port to connect your 3G modem to. An [example](http://www.aztech.com/prod_3g_hw550.html). They will use your 3G modem for Internet connectivity.
2. Use one of the PCs as a proxy. Basically, connect to the Internet on one PC, install a proxy software (e.g. squid) on this same PC and configure the rest of the browsers to use this PC as a proxy.
3. Use one of the PCs as a gateway. Basically, enable internet connection sharing on one PC, connect to the Internet on this PC and configure the rest of the PCs to use this PC as the network *gateway*.